# Nuxt content /articles not found on production

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Hey I just incorporated Nuxt content into my website
It works like a breeze on development but it breaks on production idk why
Here is the code of my page

`const articles = await $content('articles').sortBy('date', 'desc').fetch()`

and this is the error message

[GET] /blog 07:36:06:28 ERROR /articles not found at QueryBuilder.fetch (node_modules/@nuxt/content/lib/query-builder.js:190:13)

What stuff should I try out to get more info? Maybe the folder content/articles is getting lost on build?
This is my dev script

`"dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server"`

Maybe it has something to do with express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the `content` directory as a server file in `vercel.json`.

```
{
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "nuxt.config.js",
      "use": "@nuxtjs/vercel-builder",
      "config": {
        "serverFiles": [
          "content/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What if you don't use vercel, but digitalocean and kubernetes?

Comment: @Mathijs i found these articles below. They're for nuxt 2 but they should help.
https://v2.nuxt.com/deployments/digital-ocean/
https://omegion.dev/2021/03/how-to-deploy-nuxt-js-on-kubernetes-cluster-part-1/